# Join fetch like behaviour for native query in hiberanate 6

Tags: hibernate, join

Using a query like this in hibernate 5

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = """
select i.*, e.* from instrument i
   join exchange e on e.id = i.exchange_id
            
""")
List<Instrument> findAllInstrumentsHibernate5();
```

I was sure that exchange fetched as well.
After I migrated to hibernate 6 for the same query I got an exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [id] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
```

Probably due to these new changes - read data from rows in JDBC result set by a column position instead of name.

I have tried executing query like this instead:

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = """
    select i.instrument_type, i.id, i.attributes, i.ticker, i.exchange_id, i.company_id, i.currency,
           e.code, e.country_code, e.currency as exchange_currency, e.name from instrument i
                             join exchange e on e.id = i.exchange_id
            
    """)
List<Instrument> findAllInstruments();
```

**But still it doesn't lead to behaviour that I want to fetch related entity exchange in the same query, maybe somebody knows how to do it without switching to jpql?**

Btw, here are the entities :

```
@Entity
public class Instrument {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native")
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EXCHANGE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk__instrument__exchange_id__exchange"))
    private Exchange exchange;
    
}

@Entity
public class Exchange {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native")
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

Comment: By : "But still it doesn't lead to behaviour that I want to fetch related entity exchange in the same query, maybe somebody knows how to do it without switching to jpql?", do you mean that tou have the result but the related associated objects are null ?

Comment: @AmineABBAOUI yeah, the  associated objects are null in that case

Comment: could you share an example of your query result ?